# On screen keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, on-screen-keyboard

I'm working on an WPF application, that has to run on a Windows Surface Pro. And now i'm running into problems with the on screen keyboard.

I tried this solution:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Enabling-Windows-8-Touch-7fb4e6de

But this breaks the listview.

Now i have this:

```
private Process m_KeyBoard = new Process();

private void TextBox_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_KeyBoard.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
    m_KeyBoard.Start();
}
```

And this works, but i don't like it. Is there a better sollution?

And if there isn't a better solution, how can I stop the process if the textbox loses his focus?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a better solution for you, but to stop the process (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322024/starting-and-stopping-a-process-in-c-sharp-net)), call the following on the textbox's LostFocus event:

```
m_KeyBoard.Kill()
```